# Show Additional Content Based on Selection

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

```
Is this also the Risk Address:
<select name="InsuredSALicense2" id="InsuredSALicense2">
  <option>Please Select</option>
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>
```

If the answer here is "No" then a hidden drop down must be created.

```
If No, Please give details: 
<textarea name="InsuredOther License2" 
          id="InsuredOther License2" 
          cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>
<form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">
```

Say that on the form I want to create a drop down (example: "Do you...", please select yes/no): if the answer is "Yes" then drop down a section if no then don't drop down section.

This form was done in dreamweaver cs4.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this relatively easy. Using the javascript framework jQuery, you could do something like the following:

```
/* Attach an event to your dropdown menu containing Yes/No */
$("#InsuredSALicense2").change(function(){
  /* Check Value After Change */
  if (this.val() == "Yes") {
    /* Show the dropdown field */
    $("#hiddenDIV").show();
  } else {
    /* Hide the dropdown field */
    $("#hiddenDIV").hide();
  }
});
```

This example assumes your "hidden" dropdown is within a  called "hiddenDIV":

```
<div id="hiddenDIV">
  <p>Hidden drop down stuff here</p>
</div>
```

To use this code-sample, you need to reference the jQuery library from your  tag.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you wrokin in ASP.net??
If you are workin in ASP.net..you can create a hidden dropdown list on the event of Dropdownlist text change...first you can check what is the value of selected dropdown list...
let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

I think the a good solution would be doing it client-side: so generate both the textarea and the dropdown menu. Hide the one that is not the default (style="visibility: hidden" for example). Then create an onchange event on the InsuredSALicense2 listbox, which hides the not important field and shows the important one.