# Dynamic Selection Boxes

Tags: javascript, html

I would prefer to use only CSS/HTML/Javascript.

They way I am wanting to set this up is to generate a group of dropdown boxes depending on what drop down item they choose form the master list.

For example

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="">
<select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

now if they pick volvo I want a set of drop downs (with two options) that allow you to Enable or Disable volvo specific features and a separate set for Fiats. How could I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show Additional Content Based on Selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974046/show-additional-content-based-on-selection)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you dont want to use server side resources, then the only option is to create large lists of data and keep that on the client. For example:

```
var masterList = [
    { 'Volvo': 'volvo', 
      'Elements': [
        { 'SomePieceOfData', 'SomeValue' },
        { 'SomePieceOfData2', 'SomeValue2' },
        { 'SomePieceOfData3', 'SomeValue3' },
    ]},
    { 'Fiat': 'fiat', 
      'Elements': [
        { 'SomePieceOfData4', 'SomeValue4' },
        { 'SomePieceOfData5', 'SomeValue5' },
        { 'SomePieceOfData6', 'SomeValue5' },
    ]},
];
```

That way, you can simply reference your object and query it for details to show in your drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
<select id="cars" name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="model">
</select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeOptions(arr)
    {
        var options = '<select id="car-model" name="car-model">';  

        for (x = 0; x < arr.length; x++)
        {
          options += '<option value="'+arr[x]+'">'+arr[x]+'</option>';
        }

        options += '</select>';

        return options;
    }

    $(function() {
        $('#cars').change(function() {
            var volvo = ['this', 'that', 'another'],
                saab  = ['this', 'that', 'another'],
                fiat  = ['this', 'that', 'another'],
                audi  = ['this', 'that', 'another'];

            switch ($(this).val())
            {
                case 'Volvo':
                    newSelect = makeOptions(volvo);
                    break;
                case 'Saab':
                    newSelect = makeOptions(saab);
                    break;
                case 'Fiat':
                    newSelect = makeOptions(fiat);
                    break;
                case 'Audi':
                    newSelect = makeOptions(audi);
                    break;
            }

            $('#model').html(newSelect);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```